# kogrid not updating column when data changed

Tags: knockout.js, kogrid

i have simple data like this :

```
var dataFromAjax = [
     {Id : 1, Name : "Yoza", Status : 1},
     {Id : 2, Name : "Dhika", Status : 1}
];
```

and next data from ajax will have different schema. like this :

```
var nextData = [
    {Id : 1, Name : 'Yoza', Job : 'Programmer', Phone : '08788'},
    {Id : 1, Name : 'Dhika', Job : 'Designer', Phone : '99987922'}
]
```

in my piece of code :

```
self.Data = ko.observableArray();
self.Data(nextData);
self.Data.valueHasMutated();
```

the problem is column not updated. column still same like first schema, that are id, name and status. Job and Phone not rendered. how to render different schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an observableArray columnDefs to your koGrid binding for it to change. See their docs [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/Defining-Columns).

Like:

HTML binding:

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: {data: Data, columnDefs: columns}"></div>
```

Viewmodel (part only):

```
self.columns = ko.computed(function(){
    var cols = Object.keys(self.Data()[0]);
    return cols.map(function(col){
        return {
            field: col
        };
    });
});
```

You can define how you create your `columns` as long as it returns an array of objects with a `field` object. (See docs above for more info)

I created a minified fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gv6tjpwb/) to provide some example basing on your data. The data will change after 1 second (this is just for testing).

Comment: but it get extra column : '__kg_selected__' what is this? oh ya thanks for solution

Comment: oh yeah one again, with your solution how i init other columnDefs, like showGroupPanel or other? thanks

Comment: Oh "kg_selected" is because I haven't set displaySelectionCheckbox to false (But i'm using the old version of kogrid in the fiddle, kindly check if this problem still occurs in the new version, it's hard to check now cause i'm using phone right now :D), regarding the showGroupPanel or other configurations, you can add them directly in the parameters like: `<div style="height: 200px;" data-bind="koGrid: {data: Data, columnDefs: columns, displaySelectionCheckbox: false, showGroupPanel: true}">
</div>`. More configurations. https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/wiki/Configuration